# Selecting rows from mysql using regexp

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I'm trying to select specific rows from my database by using regexp, but it's not working for some reason. What am I doing wrong, and how do I fix it?

```
select response from allData where response regexp '\*([a-zA-Z]+ )+\*'
```

It's suppose to select rows like:

*kicks you *

^---With an extra space after the word, and before the asterisk. But it's not working. How do I fix it?

Comment: You probably need to escape `*`

Comment: @PaulSpiegel He's trying that with `\*`.

Comment: Use double backslashes. Also, if you need to make sure the full string is matched, use anchors: `'^\\*([a-zA-Z]+ )+\\*$'`

Comment: @Barmar, the pattern has been modified after my comment. Probably a typo.

Comment: `[*]` should also work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not escaping the `*` correctly. Backslash is both the string and regular expression escape character. In order for the regular expression engine to see the backslash that escapes the `*`, you have to escape the backslash to get it through the string parser.

```
select response from allData where response regexp '\\*([a-zA-Z]+ )+\\*'
```